# Python: Facebook Graph API - pagination request using facebook-sdk

Tags: python-3.x, facebook-graph-api, pagination

I'm trying to query Facebook for different information, for example - friends list. And it works fine, but of course it only gives limited number of results. How do I access the next batch of results?

```
import facebook
import json

ACCESS_TOKEN = ''

def pp(o):
    with open('facebook.txt', 'a') as f:
        json.dump(o, f, indent=4)


g = facebook.GraphAPI(ACCESS_TOKEN)
pp(g.get_connections('me', 'friends'))
```

The result JSON does give me paging-cursors-before and after values - but where do I put it?

Comment: did you find how to do it?

Comment: Even i have the same question.Can this be done or not?

Answer (score 4):

I'm exploring Facebook Graph API through the `facepy` library for Python (works on Python 3 too), but I think I can help.

#### TL-DR:

You need to append `&after=YOUR_AFTER_CODE` to the URL you've called (e.g: `https://graph.facebook/v2.8/YOUR_FB_ID/friends/?fields=id,name`), giving you a link like this one: `https://graph.facebook/v2.8/YOUR_FB_ID/friends/?fields=id,name&after=YOUR_AFTER_CODE`, that you should make a GET Request.

---

You'll need `requests` in order to make a get request for Graph API using your user ID (I'm assuming you know how to find it programatically) and some url similar to the one I give you below (see `URL` variable).

```
import facebook
import json
import requests

ACCESS_TOKEN = ''
YOUR_FB_ID=''
URL="https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/{}/friends?access_token={}&fields=id,name&limit=50&after=".format(YOUR_FB_ID, ACCESS_TOKEN)

def pp(o):
    all_friends = []
    if ('data' in o):
        for friend in o:
            if ('next' in friend['paging']):
                resp = request.get(friend['paging']['next'])
                all_friends.append(resp.json())
            elif ('after' in friend['paging']['cursors']):
                new_url = URL + friend['paging']['cursors']['after']
                resp = request.get(new_url)
                all_friends.append(resp.json())
             else:
                 print("Something went wrong")
             
    # Do whatever you want with all_friends...
    with open('facebook.txt', 'a') as f:
        json.dump(o, f, indent=4)


g = facebook.GraphAPI(ACCESS_TOKEN)
pp(g.get_connections('me', 'friends'))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for since I also have severe problems figureing out how to use the pagination. However, if I use your above code it gives me an error telling me "TypeError: string indices must be integers" - any idea on how to fix this?