# pagination of places in facebook sdk

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, pagination

I am down to python2 and im kinda loving it and make me say 'i wish i was curious of it earlier' but i'm stuck in pagination of places in facebook sdk (and there is not enough documentation about that on website)

I wrote a logic to iterate through pagination results but somewhere its broken badly and repeats 25 time of same results.

```
def fbPlaceFinder(geocode, query):
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=facebook_api_key, 
    version=2.7)
    places = graph.request('/search?type=place&q=' + query + '&center=' + geocode + '&distance=20000&fields=name,checkins,picture')

    allplaces = []

    while True:
        try:
            for place in places['data']:
            allplaces.append(places['data'])
        places = requests.get(places['paging']['next']).json() # add next page of results to json
    except KeyError:
        break

    return allplaces  ## returns only placeholder results
```

closest solution was [Python: Facebook Graph API - pagination request using facebook-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326198/python-facebook-graph-api-pagination-request-using-facebook-sdk) but somewhow i still couldnt figure out because this is case if more about persons, not places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will insert the same data repeatedly.

```
for place in places['data']:
        allplaces.append(places['data'])
```

I think you mean `allplaces.append(place)`?

Comment: results are better now. thank you. do you think if i made pagination right? because there is no documentation on facebook library website.

Comment: Can you retrieve lots of data then?

Comment: thank you buddy, at least its not repeating 25 times but 217 result id returns. but still feels like there is something i skipped.

Comment: From my point of view I think it is right, maybe you can refer to the similar solution you posted, and try to catch the ['after'] field too?

Comment: checking if there is ['after'] field  in those if statements like what that dude did? that dude called requests in each step and seperated in formatted urls. and his logic seemed very alien to me, i dont know if it work but definitely its worth to try. thank you sincerely, python is joy to tinker after countless js frameworks i worked by.

Answer (score 3):

2020 update: If you're using [the Facebook Business Python SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-business-sdk), pagination is handled for you! The call to `get_whatever` returns an iterator, so you can simply loop through it, and it'll eventually return all the results to you - making additional API calls as-needed.

Here's what the docs say:

> Look at the methods of an object to see what associations over which we can
> iterate. For example an `AdUser` object has a method `get_ad_accounts` which
> returns an iterator of `AdAccount` objects.

> We wrap the return value of `get_ad_accounts` with `list()`
> because `get_ad_accounts` returns an `EdgeIterator` object (located in
> `facebook_business.adobjects`) and we want to get the full list right away instead of
> having the iterator lazily loading accounts.

Here's a real-world example:

```py
from facebook_business.adobjects import adaccount
entity = adaccount.AdAccount(ad_account_id)

promoted_objects = entity.get_ad_sets(
  fields = ['name'],
  params = {'limit' : 1000}
)

print(len(promoted_objects))
# Outputs : "1000" - because this is just the first page, and we've specified 1000 per page.

all_the_data = list(promoted_objects) # This forces the iterator to grab all pages.

print("Fetched {} items".format(len(all_the_data)))
# Outputs : "Fetched 8889 items" (for me)
```

If you're curious how this magic is all happening, check out the [`iterate_edge` function](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-business-sdk/blob/a9d6df685a683e89d0d63fe95393b0bbb20b18e9/facebook_business/adobjects/abstractcrudobject.py#L548) and [the `Cursor` class](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-business-sdk/blob/a9d6df685a683e89d0d63fe95393b0bbb20b18e9/facebook_business/api.py#L697) that it returns - specifically [the `load_next_page` function.](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-business-sdk/blob/a9d6df685a683e89d0d63fe95393b0bbb20b18e9/facebook_business/api.py#L812)

Tip: An HTTP failure when fetching any page can cause an error can cause the entire iteration process to fail. So, when fetching large numbers of results, be sure to specify a high limit. Low limit = more API calls = more chance to fail. You can also implement a RetryStrategy using requests, but that's a topic for another question.